# Ionic storage GET

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I try get value from ionic storage, but it's doesn't work here. Why GET2 execute before storage.get ? My brain is broken, help please.

```
  public storageGet(key: string){
    var uid = 0;
     this.storage.get(key).then((val) => {
      console.log('GET1: ' + key + ': ' + val);
      if (val != null) { uid = val;}
    });
    console.log('GET2: ' + key + ': ' + uid);
  return uid;
  }
```

Return:

```
GET2: uid: 0
GET1: uid: 1
```

Comment: This is clearly not a problem with ionic or angular. This is how promises should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how promise works.

This code is asynchronous, all lines in the `then` callback will be execute, but you can't decide when.

The `console.log("GET2")` is executed strictly after the `storage.get`, this part is synchronous.